# Python, обмен данными между процессами

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, exchange, pipes

Имеется основной python процесс, происходящий в окружении А (python 2.7), этот процесс в какой то момент вызывает сторонний exe с несколькими аргументами, который в свою очередь создает дочерний python процесс в своем окружении Б (python 2.6) и передает ему аргументы в виде строк, дочерний процесс в результате работы должен вернуть в процесс A данные в виде объекта класса со всеми атрибутами и методами.

Есть проблемы с окружением Б - нет сокетов, добавить не могу поскольку не мое. Придумал пока только сериализацию объекта класса через pickle во временный файл из дочки и десериализацию в основном процессе.

Задумался об использовании multiprocessing.pipe, но тогда, на сколько я понимаю, из основного процесса в процесс, вызываемый сторонним exe, надо как то передать объект отправителя Pipe, но туда можно только строки пихать. А если сделаю также через временные файлы то в дочерний процесс прийдет не сам объект класса а по сути его клон, или я чего то не понимаю?. Не подскажите, как это можно организовать?

Возможно есть другие способы обмена данными между процессами, буду крайне признателен за подсказки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обмена данными между процессами в разных версиях Python, вы можете использовать механизмы межпроцессного взаимодействия (Inter-Process Communication, IPC). Как вы правильно заметили, multiprocessing.pipe может быть хорошим вариантом, но есть ограничения на передачу объектов между процессами через него.

Чтобы передать объект класса между процессами, вы можете использовать сериализацию объекта в строку и затем десериализацию обратно. Вы можете использовать библиотеку pickle для этой цели. Ваши опасения о "клонировании" объекта вроде бы обоснованы, но в большинстве случаев это будет работать нормально, если объект и его состояние могут быть корректно сериализованы и десериализованы.

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

1. В дочернем процессе (окружение Б), вы сериализуете объект класса в строку, используя
   **pickle**

> ```
> import pickle
>
> # Ваш объект класса, например:
> my_object = MyClass()
>
> # Сериализуем объект в строку
> serialized_object = pickle.dumps(my_object)
> ```

1. Затем передайте эту строку обратно в основной процесс (окружение А) через **multiprocessing.pipe** или любой другой механизм, который вам доступен.
2. В основном процессе (окружение А), десериализуйте строку обратно в объект:

> ```
> import pickle
>
> # Получите строку из дочернего процесса
>
> # Десериализуем строку обратно в объект
> my_object = pickle.loads(serialized_object)
> ```

Обратите внимание, что если объект класса содержит ссылки на другие объекты, они также должны быть сериализуемыми через **pickle**, иначе это может вызвать ошибку.

Помимо **pickle**, вы также можете рассмотреть альтернативные форматы сериализации, такие как JSON или MessagePack, в зависимости от ваших потребностей и ограничений окружения.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение, единственное уточнение осталось: если я по тому же принципу сериализации сначала в основном процессе создаю объект Pipe, из этого процесса сериализую объект "отправителя" и уже из дочки десериализую его, то точно ли десериализованный объект будет относиться именно к созданному из основного процесса объекту Pipe, или эта связь нарушится?